# Is there enough activity on this site?

Tags: discussion

I am afraid of the low activity since this site entered the public beta phase. Aren't there any questions to be asked here? I think no one should be afraid of self-answer questions: Every question and every answer embiggens the surface for search engines and the probabilty that more people are attracted to this site.

Comment: I'm a little concerned too, but there are other sites with even less activity, so I don't think they'll kill us off quite yet. But we do need to keep building the site and community.

Comment: I think our low activity is a problem, and a discussion about *how* to increase activity on the site would be productive (and may be necessary).

Comment: This one should be a menetekel to us: https://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/4296/personal-productivity

Comment: @jknappen Granted, that site was closed after nearly 2500 days in beta. We've been in beta for less than six months! So there's definitely still hope. 
Also, unrelated but thanks for teaching me the word "menetekel" because I'd never heard it before!

Answer (score 13):

## We will not get closed for low activity

StackExchange no longer closes sites solely for low activity. According to [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257614/graduation-site-closure-and-a-clearer-outlook-on-the-health-of-se-sites):

> If there's enough moderation for a public beta site to consistently remain free of spam, for flags to be cleared, and for our Be Nice policy to be upheld, your site will remain open.

While our activity is indeed quite low, we don't need to worry about being shut down for it -- so far we've done an excellent job avoiding spam and Being Nice to one another! We need to keep that up, of course, but we definitely *don't* need to panic about having our site shut down.

## That said, we should try to promote our site

I agree that our site's low activity is unfortunate, and that we'd be a better site with higher activity. But the only way to solve that is by doing something about it!

As pointed out by jknappen, there are two main ways to do this:

- Promoting this site on other places conlangers frequent. This includes **sharing links to high-quality questions and answers** to draw users of other conlanging fora to this site.
- Being more active ourselves. I definitely think we should work to post more questions and answers -- and I'll be looking to do that myself this summer! If we want people to use our site, we need to have high-quality content to draw them in!

We mods are also looking into other ways to increase participation among those already here on the site. Be on the lookout for meta posts gauging interest in potential events and challenges for site members in the near future! And if you've got an idea for something that you think would improve this site, please post a meta thread about it!

Answer (score 5):

As @Sparksbet said in her answer, we need to increase the activity on this site.

There are basically two means: Being active ourselves and drawing more people from the community here.

Being active ourselves means, keep asking and answering questions, seeing our commitment as a long term activity that is not stopped by getting a beta badge.

Drawing more people here means promoting this site on places where conlang afficionadoes hang around, this includes mailing lists and fora. It also includes some other stackexchange sites where it is possible to have community ads.